# How can we have multiple sigma algebras?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

In my textbook, one of the examples shows an $ \Omega $ that has two sigma algebras($ \mathcal F$ and $\mathcal B$). My only question is, how is it possible for there to be more than one sigma algebra? For example, suppose $ \Omega $ is {1,2}. Then the sigma algebra would be {$\Omega$, 1 , 2 , {1,2} , $\emptyset$}. What other ones could exist? Sorry if this seems like a simple question, I'm just having trouble grasping my head around it.

Comment: $\{\emptyset, \Omega\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra as well. Why would you think that a set must have only one $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: I think I'm sort of understanding it now. Would the set {1,2} still be a $ \sigma $-algebra as well?

Comment: No because a $\sigma$-algebra must have $\emptyset$ and the whole space as elements.

Comment: Oh ok, I think I get it now. So in the same manner, {$\Omega$, $\emptyset$,{1,2}) would be a sigma algebra too?

Comment: $\{1,2\}$ is just $\Omega$ (smh)

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. It makes sense now, the textbook I had just explained it in a really odd manner. If you wish, you can post an answer, and I'll be happy to accept it

Comment: I'm glad I helped. Thanks, but I don't feel like writing an answer.